How are some functions in PrivateFrameworks not usable from non-Apple signed binaries?
I know that code signing (and entitlements, plists, etc.) affects launching of binaries, or getting a task port(for debugger), but I didn't know they affect private library function calling as well. Many functions in SkyLight.framework are externally usable, as seen in CGSInternal. But some functions only work when they are called from an Apple-signed binary.
For example, the WSInfo executable in SkyLight.framework's Resources folder can be used to dump some useful debug information of your windows. It simply calls SLSSetDebugOptions which ultimately calls CGSSetDebugOptionsPSN. But it simply won't work if you copy it out and remove the signature. Signing it using my own cert does not work either.
My question is, how and where is this signature verification done in apple's systems? Does it have anything to do with the 'PSN' in the function name? Why can't I see any code related to code signature in the disassembly?
I made some preliminary search but found nothing. Maybe my google-fu is not good enough. Or I don't know the right keywords.
Update: I now have a better clue. I noticed SkyLight's complaint in Console.app and by searching that message string I narrowed down on sandbox_check_by_audit_token, but still don't know how or if I can add this token(entitlement?) to my own program.
